unsupported pubsub message: "invalidate"
I am trying to receive invalidation message from local redis setup using the client tracking feature in Redis. It basically publishes key that was updated in redis on "__redis__:invalidate" pubsub channel, so this key can be evicted from client side cache.
It throws error of unsupported pubsub message: "invalidate" for go-redis v9 but works fine for v8.
The code I am trying is :
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/redis/go-redis/v9"
    //"github.com/go-redis/redis/v8"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    redisOptions := &redis.Options{
        Addr: "localhost:6379",
        OnConnect: func(ctx context.Context, cn *redis.Conn) error {
            cid := cn.ClientID(ctx).Val()
            return cn.Process(ctx, redis.NewBoolCmd(ctx, "CLIENT", "TRACKING", "ON", "REDIRECT", fmt.Sprintf("%v", cid), "BCAST", "PREFIX", "my"))
        },
    }

    redisClient := redis.NewClient(redisOptions)

    pubsub := redisClient.Subscribe(ctx, "__redis__:invalidate")

    go func() {
        defer pubsub.Close()
        for {
            fmt.Println("Listening...")
            msg, err := pubsub.ReceiveMessage(ctx)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err) //This error is thrown
            }
            fmt.Println(msg)
        }
    }()

    time.Sleep(30 * time.Second)

}

The steps to reproduce are :

start local redis server
Run the above script
Run command SET my-key "val" in redis cli

